# password reset form, own clean method

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to write my own method for the password reset form to make some tests about the new password (length, characters,...). So I added this class to my forms.py:

```
class PasswordResetForm(SetPasswordForm):
  def clean(self):
    if 'newpassword1' in self.cleaned_data and 'newpassword2' in self.cleaned_data:
      if self.cleaned_data['newpassword1'] != self.cleaned_data['newpassword2']:
        raise forms.ValidationError(("The two password fields didn't match."))

      #here the passwords entered are the same
      if len(self.cleaned_data['newpassword1']) < 8:
        raise forms.ValidationError(("Your password has to be at least 8 characters long"))

      if not re.search('\d+', self.cleaned_data['newpassword1']) or not re.search('([a-zA-Z])+', self.cleaned_data['new  password1']):
        raise forms.ValidationError(("Your password needs to contain at least one number and one character"))

      return self.cleaned_data
```

and in the urls.py I added this:

```
url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm, {'template_name':'registration/password_reset_confirm.html',
                                                                                                                                   'set_password_form': PasswordResetForm})
```

But my own clean method isn't called. Whats wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. It was a mistake in my urls.py. It needed to be:

```
url(r'^password/reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm,{'template_name':'registration/password_reset_confirm.html','set_password_form': PasswordResetForm})
```

I don't know why I still got an password reset form and not a 404. Maybe someone can tell me. I'm a bit worried that there might still be a possible way to use the standard reset form.

Answer (score 0):

this answer may look stupid and i don't have the justification but i ran in the same problem and i solved it by replacing the

```
self.cleaned_data['newpassword1']
```

by

```
self.cleaned_data.get('newpassword1')
```

for all the clean_data set:

```
class PasswordResetForm(SetPasswordForm):
def clean(self):
  cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
  if 'newpassword1' in cleaned_data and 'newpassword2' in cleaned_data:
     if cleaned_data.get('newpassword1') != cleaned_data.get('newpassword2'):
       raise forms.ValidationError(("The two password fields didn't match."))


     if len(cleaned_data.get('newpassword1')) < 8:
      raise forms.ValidationError(("Your password has to be at least 8 characters long"))

     if not re.search('\d+', cleaned_data.get('newpassword1')) or not re.search('([a-zA-Z])+', cleaned_data.get('new  password1')):
      raise forms.ValidationError(("Your password needs to contain at least one number and one character"))

  return cleaned_data
```

Comment: Didn't do it for me. Still the same problem. When I set a breakpoint to the clean function, it isn't called. So the problem has to be elsewhere.